# What is the default file upload and file download limit file size in http requests for uploading and download huge data files using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Can anyone please suggest me ,default fileupload and download limit file size in jmeter using http requests.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: How large are the files you are trying to send? And do you really think that should be part of a load test?

Comment: In requirement they were mentioned as "Huge data files getting uploding" so i got doubt for load test and stress test can u pls suggest me how much size data files i need to upload @NielsvanReijmersdal

Comment: Huge data files getting uploaded how often? Is this the key use of the system? How many users at the same time? Do we have example files, e.g. how large are we expecting? Seems you need to get the requirements clarified before you can decide if you want to tests this.

Comment: 500 users at the same time @Niels van Reijmersdal

Comment: 500 users doing what? Do understand we cannot help you setup/configure your load test. We have not enough information and context about your system. Also it is a different question.

Comment: 500 USERS Uploading and download the files using jmeter@Niels Reijmersdal

Answer (score 0):

There is no file limit size for jMeter or HTTP. The limits are your test-machine (memory, disksize, etc) and application (configuration, disksize, etc).

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108079/how-to-increase-upload-file-size-in-jmeter?rq=1
- https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-user/201208.mbox/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461282/what-is-the-maximum-file-size-i-can-transfer-using-http-and-using-ftp

Comment: In requirement they were mentioned as "Huge data files getting uploding" so i got doubt for load test and stress test can u pls suggest me how much size data files i need to upload by default ?@NielsvanReijmersdal

Answer (score 0):

There are no limits especially if you use [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler which can stream the file directly to the network in case of upload and discard the response data in case of download.

References:

- [fileupload test with JMeter](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/fileupload-test-with-JMeter-td4267154.html)
- [HTTP Raw Request for SOAP + MTOM](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/VDqXDNDCr6w/overview)

To limit the downloaded data size to the desired value set the corresponding `kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.ResultDataLimit` property value

You can install HTTP Raw Request sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)